# Scala Actors: Returning a Future of a type other than Any.

Tags: scala, types, actor, future

I am working my way through a book on Scala Actors, and I am running into a bit of a syntactical hangup. In practice, I tend to assign my variables and function definitions as such:

```
val v: String = "blahblahblah"
def f(n: Int): Int = n+1
```

including the (return)type of the item after its name. While I know this is not necessary, I have grown comfortable with this convention and find that it makes the code more easily understood by myself. 
That being said, observe the below example:

```
class Server extends Actor {
  def act() = {
    while (true) {
      receive {
        case Message(string) => reply("Good,very good.")
      }
    }
  }
}
def sendMsg(m: Message, s: Server): Future[String] = {
  s !! m
}
```

The above code produces an error at compile time, complaining that the server returned a Future[Any], as opposed to a Future[String]. I understand that this problem can be circumvented by removing the return type from sendMsg:

```
def sendMsg(m: Message,s: Server) = s !! m
```

However, this is not consistant with my style. Is there a way that I can specify the type of Future that the server generates (as opposed to Future[Any])?

Comment: In `Akka` just call `.mapTo[Int]` after `ask` (`!!` is `ask` in your code), this will explicitly convert `Future[Any]` to `Future[String]`. Im sure there exists the same method for your actors/`Future`-s

Comment: Another related SO question can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13630585/381140)

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is a lot deeper than just style: you get a `Future[Any]` because the compiler cannot statically know better—with the current Akka actors as well as with the now deprecated scala.actors. In the absence of compile-time checks you need to resort to runtime checks instead, as idonnie already commented:

```
(actorRef ? m).mapTo[String]
```

This will chain another Future to the original one which is filled either with a `String` result, a `ClassCastException` if the actor was naughty, or with a `TimeoutException` if the actor did not reply, see [the Akka docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/actors.html#Ask__Send-And-Receive-Future).

There might be a way out soon, I’m working on an Akka extension to include statically typed channels, but that will lead to you having to write your code a little differently, with more type annotations.

Comment: What about Akka typed actors (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/typed-actors.html)? I never used them, but aren't they what you are searching for? Anyway, just to leave here more information about the design choices and philosophy behind this for people interested, read this blog post: http://letitcrash.com/post/19074284309/when-to-use-typedactors.

Comment: @Rui Gonçalves Me too never used them, but seems they also provide a runtime type check - otherwise something like `implicit m: ClassManifest[T]` will be there.

Comment: TypedActors use proxies, hence are as type-safe as normal objects and method calls; under the hood they do dynamically typed message passing. But as Rui mentioned, their applicability is quite specialized.